# How does read.csv work? What if I have a data set with different columns?

Tags: r, tidyverse, read.csv

I got a data set. When I use read.csv to import the data, I got warnings saying that some observations should have say 4 columns but actually have less than 4 columns.

When I check the data, I find that some observations are seperated into two lines as the following showed: (#3 observation)

```
Number, name, value_1, value_2
1,      'A',  2,       3
2,      'B',  4,       5
3,      'C',  7
8
4,      'D',  9,       10
5,      'E',  11,      12
```

So, I am wondering how can I solve this problem?

My dataset is large. So manually correcting the mistakes would be very time consuming.

Comment: With data that malformed you're going to have a hard time reading that into `read.csv`. What produced such an invalid csv file? It would be better to try to fix that problem than clean it after the fact in R. Otherwise you're basically going to have to treat the input like strings, turn it into a proper CSV file, and then read that with `read.csv`.

Comment: Reading CSV files with embedded newlines (as this appears to be) is problematic on several levels. First, while one might be able to infer an embedded newline in columns 1-3 (by the insufficient number of columns), a newline within column 4 would not obviously be split until one looks at the next line to see that it contains zero field-separators (commas). I don't know of any "standard" CSV parser that will infer this for you, and while not cosmically difficult, it is almost certain to be slow.

Comment: it seems that there is a wrong line break before "8". Use a text editor and fix it.

Comment: If you have any control, I would go back to the source of the data and fix it there. If it's only one line and you don't mind manual intervention, do as @tpetzoldt suggested and edit the file and fix that row (and others like it).

Comment: Agree with MrFlick and others.  If the data set is manageable you may want to import it into Excel rather than use a simple text editor.  Because then you can filter on blanks to isolate the problem rows and easily drag mis-placed values to where they belong.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the fill argument to the read.csv function to load incomplete rows with NA for missing values. The fill parameter is demonstrated here with the read.table function:

```
df <- read.table(text="Number, name, value_1, value_2
                      1,      'A',  2,       3
                      2,      'B',  4,       5
                      3,      'C',  7
                      8
                      4,      'D',  9,       10
                      5,      'E',  11,      12", 
                   sep = ",", fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df

# Number    name value_1 value_2
# 1      1       A       2       3
# 2      2       B       4       5
# 3      3       C       7      NA
# 4      8              NA      NA
# 5      4       D       9      10
# 6      5       E      11      12
```

Note that here the fourth record "name" value has not been imported as NA but as an empty string.

You can pass the same fill parameter to read.csv:

```
df <- read.csv("myfile.csv", header = T, sep = ",", fill = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If you are still having trouble importing the file with read.csv function using the fill argument then I would suggest importing the data line by line using read.table with sep="\n" (the newline character) and then clean and parse the data from the resulting strings in R rather than manually editing the file. How this cleaning would take place very much depends on the anomalies in the file but something like this works for the example data supplied but assumes that all missing values on a row are similarly missing to the right of the data that is available:

```
require(stringr)

lines <- read.table(text="Number, name, value_1, value_2\n
                      1,      'A',  2,       3\n
                      2,      'B',  4,       5\n
                      3,      'C',  7\n
                      8\n
                      4,      'D',  9,       10\n
                      5,      'E',  11,      12\n", 
                 sep = "\n", fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

record_list <- apply(lines, 1, FUN= function(x){str_squish(str_split(x, ",", simplify = T))})

# Assuming all missing values are to the right of present values on a line
na_filled <- sapply(record_list, FUN = function(x){x <- c(x, rep.int(as.character(NA), 4 - length(x)))})


df <- data.frame(t(na_filled), stringsAsFactors = F)

names(df) <- c("Number", "name", "value_1", "value_2")

df

# Number name value_1 value_2
# 1      1    A       2       3
# 2      2    B       4       5
# 3      3    C       7    <NA>
# 4      8 <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
# 5      4    D       9      10
# 6      5    E      11      12
```